# I can't get my filtered results to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I let's say I have an array of objects (pros). Those pros provide an array of services, and that array is also an array of objects with a serviceName and serviceType.

```
const pros = [
  {
    name: "Tony",
    email: "tony@mail.com",
    services: [
      { serviceName: "service1", serviceType: "type1" },
      { serviceName: "service2", serviceType: "type1" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Ryan",
    email: "ryan@mail.com",
    services: [
      { serviceName: "service3", serviceType: "type1" },
      { serviceName: "service4", serviceType: "type2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Billy",
    email: "billy@mail.com",
    services: [
      { serviceName: "service5", serviceType: "type3" },
      { serviceName: "service6", serviceType: "type5" }
    ]
  }
];
```

I also have an array of service types (categories) and a value I use for filtering which is updated on change:

```
const categories = ['All', 'type1', 'type2', 'type3', 'type4', 'type5']
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(categories[0]);
```

I'm using muiTabs to To set my filter (which is working...):

```
<AppBar
  position="static"
  color="default"
  style={{ boxShadow: "none", background: "none" }}
>
  <Tabs
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    indicatorColor="primary"
    textColor="primary"
    variant="scrollable"
    scrollButtons="auto"
    aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
  >
    {categories.map((category, idx) => {
      return (
        <Tab
          key={category}
          label={category}
          value={category}
          {...a11yProps(idx)}
        />
      );
    })}
  </Tabs>
</AppBar>;
```

Rendering all pros when the value==='All' works... But I want to filter out pros based on their serviceType attribute and render a card component. Below is the code I've written, and it makes sense in my mind but I'm clearly missing something or doing something wrong because I can't seem to get the cards to render with the filters.

```
{pros.length > 0 && pros.map(pro => {
                  if(value==='All'){
                    return(
                      <Grid item xs={12} md={6} key={pro.email} style={{padding: 5}}>
                        <FavoriteProCard pro={pro}/>
                      </Grid>)
                  } else {
                    pro.services.filter((service) => {
                      const serviceType = service.serviceType
                      if(serviceType.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()) {
                          console.log(pro.name)
                          //I am getting their name here but why no render???
                          return (
                          <Grid item xs={12} md={6} key={pro.email} style={{padding: 5}}>
                            <FavoriteProCard pro={pro}/>
                          </Grid>)
                          } 
                        })
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Array.filter()` function takes predicate function as an argument. Predicate function must return *boolean*. Non-boolean return value is considered `false`.

Please change your implementation to:

```
pros.length > 0 && pros.map(pro => {
    if (value === 'All') {
      return (
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6} key={pro.email} style={{padding: 5}}>
          <FavoriteProCard pro={pro}/>
        </Grid>)
    } else {
      return pro.services
        .filter((service) => {
          const serviceType = service.serviceType

          // return true if service should be shown
          return serviceType.toLowerCase() === value.toLowerCase()
        })
        .map(service => { // <-- Chain filtered services to .map() to be rendered
          console.log(pro.name)
          //I am getting their name here but why no render???
          return (
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6} key={pro.email} style={{padding: 5}}>
              <FavoriteProCard pro={pro}/>
            </Grid>)
        }
    }
  )
```